# how to get specific nodes in xml file with python

Tags: python, xml

im searching for a way to get a specific tags .. from a very big xml document 
with python dom built in module

for example :

```
<AssetType longname="characters" shortname="chr" shortnames="chrs">
  <type>
    pub
  </type>
  <type>
    geo
  </type>
  <type>
    rig
  </type>
</AssetType>

<AssetType longname="camera" shortname="cam" shortnames="cams">
  <type>
    cam1
  </type>
  <type>
    cam2
  </type>
  <type>
    cam4
  </type>
</AssetType>
```

i want to retrieve the value of children of AssetType node who got attribute (longname= "characters" )
to have the result of `'pub','geo','rig'`
please put in mind that i have more than 1000 < AssetType> nodes 

thanx in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't mind loading the whole document into memory:

```
from lxml import etree
data = etree.parse(fname)
result = [node.text.strip() 
    for node in data.xpath("//AssetType[@longname='characters']/type")]
```

You may need to remove the spaces at the beginning of your tags to make this work.

Comment: This is my approach as well. Keep in mind it requires installing the lxml module, which isn't part of the default Python libraries. However, I'm using it in a project right now where some of the XML files are 65 meg in size and it doesn't complain (as opposed to the script's author).

Comment: +1 for `lxml.etree`, which is vastly superior to default installation of `ElementTree`.

Answer (score 9):

Assuming your document is called `assets.xml` and has the following structure:

```
<assets>
    <AssetType>
        ...
    </AssetType>
    <AssetType>
        ...
    </AssetType>
</assets>
```

Then you can do the following:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree
tree = ElementTree()
root = tree.parse("assets.xml")
for assetType in root.findall("//AssetType[@longname='characters']"):
    for type in assetType.getchildren():
        print type.text
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [pulldom API](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.pulldom.html) to handle parsing a large file, without loading it all into memory at once.  This provides a more convenient interface than using SAX with only a slight loss of performance.

It basically lets you stream the xml file until you find the bit you are interested in, then start using [regular DOM operations](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.html) after that.

```
from xml.dom import pulldom

# http://mail.python.org/pipermail/xml-sig/2005-March/011022.html
def getInnerText(oNode):
    rc = ""
    nodelist = oNode.childNodes
    for node in nodelist:
        if node.nodeType == node.TEXT_NODE:
            rc = rc + node.data
        elif node.nodeType==node.ELEMENT_NODE:
            rc = rc + getInnerText(node)   # recursive !!!
        elif node.nodeType==node.CDATA_SECTION_NODE:
            rc = rc + node.data
        else:
            # node.nodeType: PROCESSING_INSTRUCTION_NODE, COMMENT_NODE, DOCUMENT_NODE, NOTATION_NODE and so on
           pass
    return rc


# xml_file is either a filename or a file
stream = pulldom.parse(xml_file) 
for event, node in stream:
    if event == "START_ELEMENT" and node.nodeName == "AssetType":
        if node.getAttribute("longname") == "characters":
            stream.expandNode(node) # node now contains a mini-dom tree
            type_nodes = node.getElementsByTagName('type')
            for type_node in type_nodes:
                # type_text will have the value of what's inside the type text
                type_text = getInnerText(type_node)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [xml.sax](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.sax.html) module. Build your own handler and inside [startElement](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.sax.handler.html#xml.sax.handler.ContentHandler.startElement) you should check, whether name is AssetType. This way you should be able to only act, when AssetType node is processed.

[Here](http://code.google.com/p/rpgdirector/source/browse/trunk/rpg/serialization/plans.py) you have example handler, which shows, how to build one (though it's not the most pretty way, at that point I didn't know all the cool tricks with Python ;-)).

Answer (score 1):

You could use xpath, something like "//AssetType[longname='characters']/xyz".

For XPath libs in Python see http://www.somebits.com/weblog/tech/python/xpath.html

Answer (score 1):

Similar to eswald's solution, again stripping whitespace, again loading the document into memory, but returning the three text items at a time

```
from lxml import etree

data = """<AssetType longname="characters" shortname="chr" shortnames="chrs"
  <type>
    pub
  </type>
  <type>
    geo
  </type>
  <type>
    rig
  </type>
</AssetType>
"""

doc = etree.XML(data)

for asset in doc.xpath('//AssetType[@longname="characters"]'):
  threetypes = [ x.strip() for x in asset.xpath('./type/text()') ]
  print threetypes
```